# Microsoft.ApplicationInsights missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having problem with starting ASP.NET MVC5 application. Everything was working fine until now. While starting application I am getting below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights,
>   Version=1.2.3.490, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=1.2.3.490,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 1.2.3 installed. I also tried clean, rebuild, restart computer, restart computer and leave the room etc etc.

Does someone have any idea how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a message like:

```
Could not load file or assembly '[Any-Package-Name], Version=[Any-Version]
```

This mean that you have issues with compatibility between different projects. In my case I had the nuget package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights with version 2.8.1 and one of the projects had 2.4. So I got RunTime Error, you need to have the same versions of the nuget packages that you are using in all your projects for not having this errors.

> SOLUTION:

- Right click on solution
- Manage Nuget Packages for Solution
- Search the
  package which you are having the issue
- Click all the projects that are using the nuget package
- Select the version for install/update in all of them
- Click "Install"
- Rebuild your Solution

Answer (score 3):

I installed the new version with `Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.10.0` and I got the same error.
I added this line into Web.config under `<runtime><assemblyBinding ...>` and it seems working for me, make sure to have `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll` file in the bin folder as well. Good luck.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.10.0.0" newVersion="2.10.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling the package using NuGet package manager. Install an updated version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Nugget package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget to enable nlog recognize Application insight and reference it.

I had this same problem with a project I worked on with .Net Core 3.1 After I installed the Nugget package it was fine.